# Load Pdf in angular popup

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I wanted to load pdf in popup and I tried to implement as in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-pdf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Here the pdf loads in popup but I'm facing issue when I try to add the link dynamically. Below is the code I tried. Here I'm passing srclink from typescript but it is not getting assigned

```
`<div #outsideElement>

  <div class="modal-view-container">
    <div #modalView class="modal view">
      <div class="modal-view-details">
        <p style="text-align: center;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">
          <object data="srclink" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="592px;"> </object>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind any value to your views by [Bindings](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax). if you want to use `One way binding` you have change your code like this.

```
<p style="text-align: center;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">
      <object [data]="srclink" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="592px;"> </object>
</p>
```

But to bind external url in your views you have to [sanitize](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) your urls.

```
this.srclink = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      "external_url_to_pdf"
);
```

I have edited your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-pdf-ceznvz?file=src/app/app.component.ts) upvote/accept if it helps